# MEAN App: Using two servers at the same time. Express, Nodejs, Angular 6(Angular CLI)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, angular

I tried to connect the backend(Nodejs, Expressjs) to the front-end(Angular 6). 
But some issue is there.

For back-end the port is `http://localhost:3000` and

for front-end the port is `http://localhost:4200`.

while using the backend port, it was saving the users details in Mongodb db but
While loading the app and signing-up with `localhost:4200`,

It is giving an error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

Here is the code
**`server.js`** file

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

var api = require('./server/routes/api');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/meanshopcart')));

app.use('/api', api.router);

app.post('/sign-up', api.signup);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/meanshopcart/index.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, function(err){
    if(err){
       return console.log('something bad happened', err);
    }
    console.log("Server is running..!!");
});
```

Here is my route folder `api.js`

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../models/users');

const db = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/meanshopapp';
mongoose.connect(db, function(err){
    console.log("mongo connection done");
    if(err){
        console.log("Error.."+err);
    }
});

router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    console.log("get api ");
    User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;

  // object of all the users
   console.log(users);
  });
    res.send(users);
});

function signup(req, res, next){
    console.log("new user entered");

    var newUser = new User(req.body);

    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("error saving user");
        }
        else{
            console.log("user inserted");
           
        }
    })
};

module.exports = {router, signup};
```

Here is my component file `sign-up.component.html`

```html
<form class="form-style-9" 
      [formGroup]="userForm"
      (ngSubmit)= "registerUser(userForm.value)" >
<ul>
<li><span>Name</span>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" />
</li>
    <li><span>Email Id</span>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email"/>
    </li>
    <li><span>Password</span>
     <input type="password" name="password" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"/>
    </li>
<li><span>Phone No</span>
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Phone" formControlName="phoneNo" />
   
</li>
<li><span>Address</span>
<textarea name="address" class="field-style" placeholder="Address" formControlName="address"></textarea>
</li>
<li>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
</li>
    <li align="right">
    <a routerLink="/userlogin">Back to Sign In</a>
        </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

`sign-up.component.ts` I think this file is not working.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-up',
  templateUrl: './sign-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-up.component.css']
})
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router) { }
  
  userForm;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userForm =  new FormGroup ({
        name: new FormControl(""),
        email: new FormControl(""),
        password: new FormControl(""),
        phoneNo: new FormControl(""),
        address: new FormControl("")
    });
  }
  
   registerUser(formdata:any): void {
   let theForm = this.userForm.value;
      this.userService.addUser(theForm).subscribe(data => {
          if (data.success === false) {
            this.toastr.error(data.message);
          } else {
          console.log("hello");
            this.toastr.success(data.message);
            this.router.navigate(['/userlogin']);
          }
          this.userForm.reset();
      });
    }
}
```

Here is the user service i am using 'user.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  
  addUser(oUser) {
        let headers = new Headers ({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this._http.post('/sign-up', JSON.stringify(oUser), options).pipe(
            map((response: Response) => response.json()));
  }
}
```

I dont know what is the problem. I am using mean for the first time and how to connect the frontend and backend is the main issue i am facing.

Comment: Try using `this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/sign-up'` as the URL of your Angular service.

Comment: yeah it worked but why this is not working                          
   `registerUser(formdata:any): void {
   let theForm = this.userForm.value;
      this.userService.addUser(theForm).subscribe(data => {
          if (data.success === false) {
            this.toastr.error(data.message);
          } else {
          console.log("hello");
            this.toastr.success(data.message);
            this.router.navigate(['/userlogin']);
          }
          this.userForm.reset();
      });
    }` .

Comment: `why this is not working` isn't a question. A answered the first one, you should now delete this question and create a new one.